# How to make Gitlab CI not apply variable when the variable is in file

Tags: bash, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have created a GitLab pipeline and predefined variable (type file). That file contains a variable `${myVar}` that should not has to be applied before some steps of the job.
I found that when I open that file using `cat`, the `${myVar}` disappeared. Looks like it was applied but with an empty string since its content has not yet been generated.

Question: how to tell GitLab CI to ignore variables in the variable file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is fixed. All you need to do is to add one more `$` sign before the variable. Hence instead of `${myVar}` you need to specify `$${myVar}` in this case GitLab CI will not apply the variable

Answer (score 0):

As of Gitlab 13.7 you can disable variable expansion for the variable (enabled by default). See:

https://gitlab.nposervices.com/help/ci/variables/index#expand-cicd-variables

[image]